# unity get mesh after scaling

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, mesh

I am trying to get scaled vertices from a mesh after scaling the gameObject.
The gameObject will be printed scaled in the editor but if I print the vertices of mesh, they will not be scaled.

```
gameObject.transform.localScale *= 10;
_mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
//mesh.recalculateAllStuff if it is not done before get the mesh
for (int i = 0; i < _mesh.vertexCount; i++)
{
print(_mesh.vertices) //Not right scale
}
```

I am wondering how it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work if you want the scaled points, local to world position:

```
var scale = 12f;

gameObject.transform.localScale *= scale;
_mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
for (int i = 0; i < _mesh.vertexCount; i++)
{

    print(transform.TransformPoint(_mesh.vertices[i]));
}
```

If you want relative scaled points, try multiplying the _mesh.vertices[i] components by the local scale vector components - using Vector3.Scale:

Comment: I still don't understand why when I change local space scale and get the mesh, vertex scale are not updated (it's seem to be the transformation matrix local to world space that is only updated but this one is not call automatiqually when I ask printing, that's right?)

Comment: There's an important reason for that. It makes the mesh data non-destructive. Basically it's because Unity keeps the original mesh positions, so in case you change the local scaling, it will be able to have the clean, untainted original